# If statement not working yet used correctly

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private var etEmail: String? = null
private var etPass: String? = null
private var etPass2: String? = null
private lateinit var btn: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
    // Initialising
    auth= Firebase.auth
    etEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email).text.toString().trim()
    etPass = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pass).text.toString()
    etPass2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_pass2).text.toString()
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_create)
    
    //Dialog
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog)
    

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.show()

        if (isValid(etEmail, etPass, etPass2)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

}
private fun isValid(email: String?, pass: String?, pass2: String?): Boolean{
    return if (email.isNullOrEmpty() && pass.isNullOrEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fill in the blanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    }else if (pass != pass2){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    }else{
        true
    }
}
```

I am trying to check if the user has entered his email and password. But when I test the app it brings up this toast ' Fill in the blanks ' in the private is valid function yet I have entered an email and password.

Comment: You are getting the text from the `EditText`s after the layout is created, so when they are empty. You should retrieve them inside the on click listener instead, which is invoked when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in this part:

```
etEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email).text.toString().trim()
etPass = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pass).text.toString()
etPass2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_pass2).text.toString()
```

You retrieve `String` values before any changes were made by user.
You should get them only after user finished typing and clicked the button, so like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener {
    dialog.show()

    val etEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email).text.toString().trim()
    val etPass = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pass).text.toString()
    val etPass2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_pass2).text.toString()
    
    if (isValid(etEmail, etPass, etPass2)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    dialog.dismiss()
}
```

This way you can remove this part completely:

```
private var etEmail: String? = null
private var etPass: String? = null
private var etPass2: String? = null
```

When you have `private var` fields in your view class, it's usually a code smell. Of course sometimes you have to do that for very specific functionality, but you should avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with `private var` fields - sometimes you need to store some changing state, so you need a `var`, and making things `private` is always good practice. But making things nullable just so you can initialise them with something, that's definitely something you should avoid, and that's what `lateinit` is for (also `lazy` but you have to be careful with that for `View`s, especially in Fragments)

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes, `private var` is fine, but it's a mess when you do that in your view. I could argue that storing state inside view should be reduced to minimum, and instead view should create local variables only when needed, which would prevent bugs such a desynchronization between stored state and actual state. That's one reason why we use `ViewModel`'s, either using MVI or MVVM arch to store view state, and that state is source of truth. If you store state in your view, you have 2 states in a view (state inside child views like EditText and state stored in variables).

Comment: Not to mention - android specific - stored state will be cleared when fragment is recreated (OP is using activity, but in this day and age we usually do actual screens with Fragments), and that includes all variables. TL;DR use ViewModels. But I guess I'm digging too deep in conext of OP's question

Comment: In Android `View`s will literally store and restore their own state, in some cases you have to force them to stop doing it because you're handling that yourself and it ends up interfering! It's not that clean and simple in reality - but even if you are designing a very clean architecture (which is definitely a good thing IMO) there are still cases where you might want to store some transient state in the UI layer, that isn't worth persisting. But realistically most people aren't following those guidelines, so "don't use a var in a fragment" as a rule feels a bit too blunt and misleading to me

Comment: Like I get your point (and I agree with it on some levels!) I just think it needs a particular context and understanding that people might not have, so saying it without that detailed explanation can do more harm than good I think. People need to understand the *why* before they start applying it as a rule and complicating things for themselves because they think it's something they should always avoid. Meanwhile the OP (and no shade against them) is storing the contents of text fields when the Activity starts - they're not at the level where that advice makes sense, y'know? That's all!

Comment: Yep, you are right. Sorry I made it more complicated than it should be in this context :)

Comment: no worries! And I mean you're right, it *does* tie into the problem here - we've just gotta be careful about how we explain it, or if it's worth getting into at all (although hey this conversation gives a bit of explanation for anyone who's interested now!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do this:

```
private val etEmail get() = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email).text.toString().trim()
private val etPass get() = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pass).text.toString()
private val etPass2 get() = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_pass2).text.toString()
```

So they still behave like properties and you don't have to change your click listener code, but every time you read them they look up the *current contents* of each `EditText`. They're basically lookup functions.

Because they call `findViewById` you have to make sure you only access them *after* the `Activity` has its `view` set up (e.g. through `setContentView`) - but since you're only reading those properties through button clicks, which definitely can only happen after that, you're good. It's similar to `lateinit` - you just have to be mindful of when the property is read, and make sure that it will be safe to do so at that point

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to cast EditText to toString (So it will never be null)

For myself I don't see the point to use .isNullOrEmpty()
instead I will use isEmpty() so the value you pass can't not be null
to make it less confusion.

Please consider Using ViewBinding It would make your code more clean and more easy to manage and it's guarantee that you will get right view from your xml file. and it will never be null.

In your case I would do something like this

```
class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
private fun String.isEmailValid() : Boolean = android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this).matches()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    // Initialising
    auth = Firebase.auth
    //Dialog
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog)


    binding.btn_create.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.show()
        val emailText = binding.et_email.text.toString()
        val passwordText = binding.pass.text.toString()
        val confirmPasswordText = binding.et_pass2.text.toString()
        val result = isValid(emailText,passwordText,confirmPasswordText)
        Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        if(result == "Done")//todo{}
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

}

private fun isValid(email: String, password: String, confirmPassword: String): String {
    if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || confirmPassword.isEmpty()) return "Fill in the blanks"
    if (password != confirmPassword) return "Password do not match"
    if (email.isEmailValid()) return "Done"

    return "Invalid Email"
}
```

}

> For your problem like everybody said. because you init EditText value to
> variable before you click button. that's why value always be "" or empty strings. because of it is default value of EditText.text.toString().